# Moving or copying data from one node to another in firebase database

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to move my data present at one node i.e cart_details/UID to another node orders/UID/order1.
I tried different ways of doing it but all seem to be a bit confusing. Is there any built-in functionality or method that could possibly make the job easier?
Any help is appreciated.

I have attached the image for the same. [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yKzB.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you use the following lines of code:

```
public void copyRecord(Firebase fromPath, final Firebase toPath) {
    fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue(), new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
                    if (firebaseError != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Copy failed!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", firebaseError.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    });
}
```

This is a copy and not a move operation as you probably see, so the original record will remain at its original place. If you would like to delete, you can use the `removeValue()` method on the `from path` just after the `System.out.println("Success");`.

**Edit: (03 May 2018).**

Here is the code for using the new API.

```
private void copyRecord(DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isComplete()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Copy failed!");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    };
    fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Alex Mamo, will surely try that!!

Comment: Keep me posted.