# How to update the key without losing the child data in Firebase Realtime database?

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
FavoriteData  //This is the parent
  ReferenceID // Reference ID is the ID of device if there is no account else the user ID
   PushKey //Key generated when pushing an item in database
     "name": "John Doe"
     "age": "25"      
   PushKey
     "name": "Royal Smith" 
     "age": "20"
```

> **Is there a way to update the reference ID, I want to change it from the device ID into User ID if they sign in thier account**

Comment: There's no way to rename a _key_. You'll have to read the value, set again with update key and delete the previous one.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147779/failed-to-parse-note-when-adding-firebase-completelistener/50153774) will definitely help.