# I want to get the qna list through firebase, but I can't get the list

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a list of qna in the firebase. I want to print this out.

[image]

But my output list doesn't show anything.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ctRB.png

QNA Activity

```
public class QnaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView qnaRv;
    private ArrayList<ModelQna> qnaList;
    private AdapterQna adapterQna;
    private ImageButton writeBtn;
    private ImageButton backbtn;
    private TextView tabQnaTv;
    private RelativeLayout QnaRl;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_qna);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        qnaRv = findViewById(R.id.qnaRv);

        tabQnaTv = findViewById(R.id.tabQnaTv);

        QnaRl = findViewById(R.id.QnaRl);

        backbtn = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);

        writeBtn = findViewById(R.id.writeBtn);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        loadAllQna();
        showQnaUI();


        backbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        writeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddQnaActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        tabQnaTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //load products
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadAllQna() {
        qnaList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapterQna = new AdapterQna(this, qnaList);
        qnaRv.setAdapter(adapterQna);

        //get all products
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employees");
        reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Qna").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //before getting reset List
                qnaList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelQna modelQna = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelQna.class);
                    qnaList.add(modelQna);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseerror) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void showQnaUI() {
        //show orders ui and hide products ui
        QnaRl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class ModelFaq {
    private String faqId,faqTitle,faqContent, timestamp,uid,faqCategory;

    public ModelFaq() {


    }
    public ModelFaq(String faqId, String faqTitle, String faqContent, String timestamp, String uid, String faqCategory) {
        this.faqId = faqId;
        this.faqTitle = faqTitle;
        this.faqContent = faqContent;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.faqCategory = faqCategory;
    }

    public String getFaqId() {
        return faqId;
    }

    public void setFaqId(String faqId) {
        this.faqId = faqId;
    }

    public String getFaqTitle() {
        return faqTitle;
    }

    public void setFaqTitle(String faqTitle) {
        this.faqTitle = faqTitle;
    }

    public String getFaqContent() {
        return faqContent;
    }

    public void setFaqContent(String faqContent) {
        this.faqContent = faqContent;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getFaqCategory() {
        return faqCategory;
    }

    public void setFaqCategory(String faqCategory) {
        this.faqCategory = faqCategory;
    }
}
```

Qna Adapter

```
public class AdapterQna extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterQna.HolderQna> {

    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<ModelQna> qnaList;

    public AdapterQna(Context context, ArrayList<ModelQna> qnaList) {
        this.context = context ;
        this.qnaList = qnaList ;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HolderQna onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflate layout
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.qna_item, parent, false);
        return new HolderQna(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderQna holder, int position) {

             ModelQna modelQna = qnaList.get(position);
        String id = modelQna.getQnaId();
        String uid = modelQna.getUid();
        String qnaContent = modelQna.getQnaContent();
        String qnaTitle = modelQna.getQnaTitle();
        String timestamp = modelQna.getTimestamp();
        //set data
        holder.titleTextView.setText(qnaTitle);
        holder.ContentTextView.setText(qnaContent);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //handle item clicks, show item details
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //handle item clicks, show item details
            }
        });



    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return qnaList.size();
    }

   class HolderQna extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        /*holds views of recyclerview*/


        private TextView titleTextView, ContentTextView;

        public HolderQna(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_post_title);
            ContentTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_post_content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pq6ao215/

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change the code in your `HolderQna` to:

```
   class HolderQna extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        /*holds views of recyclerview*/


        private TextView titleTextView, ContentTextView;

        public HolderQna(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_post_title);
            ContentTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_post_content);
        }

        public void bind(qna: ModelQna){
        
        titleTextView.setText(qna.qnaTitle);
        ContentTextView.setText(qna.qnaContent);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //handle item clicks, show item details
            }
        });
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //handle item clicks, show item details
            }
        });
        }
    }
```

And your `onBindViewHolder` override of the `AdapterQna` to:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderQna holder, int position) {

             ModelQna modelQna = qnaList.get(position);
        String id = modelQna.getQnaId();
        String uid = modelQna.getUid();
        String qnaContent = modelQna.getQnaContent();
        String qnaTitle = modelQna.getQnaTitle();
        String timestamp = modelQna.getTimestamp();
        //set data
        holder.bind(modelQna);
    }
```

Finally change your `loadQna()` function declaration as follows:

```
 private void loadAllQna() {
        qnaList = new ArrayList<>();

        //get all products
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employees");
        reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Qna").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //before getting reset List
                qnaList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelQna modelQna = dataSnapshot.getValue(ModelQna.class);
                    qnaList.add(modelQna);
                }
                adapterQna = new AdapterQna(this, qnaList);
                qnaRv.setAdapter(adapterQna);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseerror) {
            Log.e("QnaActivity", databaseError.toString());

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see in your screenshot, the `Qna` node it's not nested under any UID, but directly under the `Employees` node. So when you attach a listener to the following node:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employees");
reference.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("Qna").addValueEventListener(/*...*/);
```

You will not be able to get any results, because such a reference doesn't exist. To solve this, you either create a reference that points exactly to "Qna":

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference qnaRef = db.child("Employees").child("Qna");
qnaRef.addValueEventListener(/*...*/);
```

Or you [move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147779/how-to-copy-a-record-from-a-location-to-another-in-firebase-realtime-database) the "Qna" node under the UID of the user, and leave the code unchanged.

Besides that, there is also another problem. The name of the fields in your `ModelFaq` class are different than the name of the properties in your database. You have in your `ModelFaq` class four fields called `faqId`, `faqTitle`, `faqContent`, `faqCategory`, all starting with **faq** while in the database I see that the names are different, `qnaId`, `qnaTitle`, `qnaContent`, `qnaCategory`, all are starting wiht **qna**, and this is **not** correct. So in order to be able to map a node into an object of type `ModelFaq`, the names **must** match. The only two fields that match are the `timestamp` and the `uid`.

In this case, you have two solutions. The first one would to change the name of your fieds in the `ModelFaq` class according to what it already exists in the database or you can use the [PropertyName](https://%5BPropertyName%5D(https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/PropertyName)) annotation in front of the getters like this:

```
@PropertyName("qnaId")
public String getFaqId() {
    return faqId;
}
```

Comment: Hey there. 
Have you tried my solution above, does it work? Or can I help you with other information?