# How to query data in Firebase using userID in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to query the information of user from User Node and then display it in my html table, as of this moment I can only query the status child of the Request Node in my Firebase database to my html table.

How do I query the information of every user in every node where his uid is present? 
Here is my structure, as of now I can display the pending status. Since the user has only 1 uid, I am thinking that diplaying the names of each user beside their pending status is possible.

[image: Target Data]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLt81.png)

here's how I query pending,

```
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('Request').child('Pending');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(data){
       var ReqStatus = data.val().request_status;
      content +='<tr>'
      content +='<td>' + ReqStatus+ '</td>'; 
      content +='</tr>';
});
    $('#mytable').append(content);
}
);
```

Comment: Why not simply save the name with the pending status?

Comment: @AndréKool how do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate your data so you have the users name with their user info and their pending request. So a request will look like: `UserID : {request_status: pending , name: Theodore }`

Comment: @AndréKool since I am adding the data in request from the android app, is there any way I can duplicate it through javascript? because my laptop is so slow on running android studio

Comment: @Theodore You can duplicate the data using Cloud Functions, which runs JavaScript. You can also do it from a web page, but that won't always be running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also load the user data for each request, you'll need to use an additional listener. The simplest approach is something like this:

```
var root = firebase.database().ref();
var database = root.child('Request').child('Pending');
database.once('value', function(snapshot){
  snapshot.forEach(function(data){
      var reqStatus = data.val().request_status;
      var uid = data.key;
      root.child('User').child(uid).once('value', function(userSnapshot) {
        var username = userSnapshot.val().username;
        content += '<tr>'
        content += '<td>' + username+ '</td><td>' + reqStatus+ '</td>'; 
        content += '</tr>';
      })
  });
  $('#mytable').append(content);
});
```

A few notes on this approach:

1. You're performing a lot more calls to Firebase, but the performance will usually be quite good since [Firebase pipelines those requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).
2. If a user has multiple requests, you're loading the node for that user multiple times. If this is a real use-case for your app, you might want to keep a cache of recently loaded users.
3. This code loads the entire user node. If you need just their name, you could listen on the `username` child node to reduce the bandwidth usage: `root.child('User').child(uid).child('username').once('value'...`.
4. As André commented: you might instead want to store the username of the author in each request node, to reduce the number of reads and keep the code simpler. To do that in JavaScript is fairly simple:

   ```
   var root = firebase.database().ref();
   var database = root.child('Request').child('Pending');
   database.once('value', function(snapshot){
     snapshot.forEach(function(data){
         root.child('User').child(data.key).child('username').once('value', function(userSnapshot) {
           data.ref.update({ username: userSnapshot.val() });
         })
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: I will try this sir, thank you very much for your help. I will inform you later with the results!

Comment: The first snippet doesn't work sir, may web console says `TypeError: userSnapshot.val(...) is null`

Comment: I tried your 2nd snippet which André suggested and it worked. Thank you very much I will now query the data inside the uid in pending. Thanks!

Comment: `TypeError: userSnapshot.val(...) is null`: that means that the user doesn't exist. You'll want to add a check for `if (userSnapshot.exists())` to counter that if this is a realistic use-case in your app.

Comment: sir, now that I can see my data inside my table with the username and request status, i have an approve button and delete button beside it, if the admin clicks the approve button it will open a modal and then if he click the approve button again the data on that column should be moved to pending. How do I do that? Should I post a new question here?