# How to copy data from one table to another table in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tables - cartOrders and placedOrders. cartOrders is used to add products to cart, and placedOrders is activated when the user presses "Place Order" button.
I need to copy data from cartOrders to placedOrders when the user clicks the "Place Order" button, but I'm not able to do so.

```
cartDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("cartOrders");
cartQuery = cartDatabase.child(orderID).orderByChild("productQuantity").startAt(1);
placedOrdersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("placedOrders");
placedOrderQuery = placedOrdersDatabase.child("orderID");
placeOrderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        cartDatabase.child(orderID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Logic to add data to data to placedOrders.
                String name = dataSnapshot.child("productName").getValue(String.class);
                System.out.println("ProductName: " + name);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OrderPlacedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("ORDER_ID", orderID);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

In the code, I was checking if the code is picking up the data from the database, but it wasn't. The output is `null`. Both the tables have the same structure.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

My cartOrders table structure:

```
cartOrders:
----------OrderID:
-----------------ProductID:
---------------------------ProductID:
---------------------------ProductName:
---------------------------ProductPrice:
---------------------------ProductQty:
```

Comment: have you solved the problem?

Comment: @Ticherhaz yes.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex Mamo answered this question on a different question.

```
private void copyRecord(Query fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {

        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                        if (task.isComplete()) {

                            System.out.println("Complete");

                        } else {

                            System.out.println("Failed");

                        }

                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };

        fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);

    }
```

The code works fine.
Link:[Moving or copying data from one node to another in firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44809824/moving-or-copying-data-from-one-node-to-another-in-firebase-database)